# Disable IntelliJ kotlin starred Imports?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, autocomplete, kotlin

in java i have star import disabled and it works correctly. but in kotlin when i import UUID it adds
`import java.util.*` instead of `import java.util.UUID`. there is no `<alt>+enter` option to change it, i see no option in settings to change it. any idea how to change this behavior?

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4548.28, built on January 30, 2018

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can configure this in the settings. Go to *Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Imports* in the preferences dialog. The `java.util` package is probably listed in **Packages to Use Import with '*'**.

[image]

Comment: I am new in Kotlin. What is the idea of using the star syntax for the java.util package?

Comment: @entenfuss The idea is that an asterisk would import all symbols declared in the module, without having to import each one individually.
This has upsides (fewer lines of code, less duplication) and downsides (implicit, names may clash etc).

Comment: @YuriShatrov I expressed myself badly. What's the idea with Kotlin, why is this handled differently than Java by default? Does that seem to be a best practice?!